# How to locate input file on Run?

Tags: ada, gnat

Using GNAT Studio I have a project with a Main and an input file. The latter is next to the project file. I want to pass the path to the input file as argument to Main Run. How to do that?

(In Visual Studio I'd add it to the project and set "Copy to output directory", then locate it relative the output dir.)

Comment: Perhaps 'for Exec_Dir use ".";' is one way of doing it. Moving the mountain.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up putting the output files in the project directory and run Main from there:

```
for Exec_Dir use ".";
```